# Prompt User If Window service is stopped

Tags: c#, asp.net, service, window

I want to give notification to user if window service is stopped.How can I get status:start/stop in Code Behind(c#)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if your using window services you already have included the reference of the `System.ServiceProcess` in your Project.

The thing you have to do to get the status of your windows service is to follow the below steps.

**Step 1:** include the assembly

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
```

**Step 2:**

create your service

```
private ServiceController yourService = new ServiceController("yourService");
```

**Step 3:**

```
if (yourService.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
        this.labelStatus.Text = "Running...";

else if (yourService.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
        this.labelStatus.Text = "Stopped.";

else if (yourService.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending)
        this.labelStatus.Text = "Starting...";

else if (yourService.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)
        this.labelStatus.Text = "Stopping...";

else if (yourService.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Paused || yourService.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.PausePending)
        this.labelStatus.Text = "Pause";
else
        this.labelStatus.Text = "Processing";
```

`labelStatus` is just a label to which you are setting your windows service status to show the user.

This is the way you can easily do it and handle any kind of status of your windows service.

In these if else blocks, You can do whatever you want to do according to service status. You can show on and off icons depending upon the start and stop states of your window service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) component to connect to and control the behavior of existing services. When you create an instance of the ServiceController class, you set its properties so that it interacts with a specific Windows service. You can then use the class to start, stop, and otherwise manipulate the service. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sywbez17%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to see how to add it and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for detailed working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System.ServiceProcess;    
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(SERVICENAME);    
if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
{
    // do anything
}
```